# Helm: change shortcuts of the actions

Tags: helm, helm-sources

In helm, when you press `TAB`, you have access to the actions corresponding to the current entry. By default, they are bound to `[F1]`,`[F2]`... But I don't like these shortcuts for several reasons:

1. the `F{n}` keys are not easy to access on a keyboard
2. if you have more than 12 entries, then you don't have any keybinding for them
3. it's hard to associate any mnemonic with `F{n}` keys

So here is my question: how could I change the shortcuts of an helm action? I'm interested both when I wrote my own code, but also if possible to change them globally.

Here is a MWE:

```
(helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Animal"
                 :candidates '("Duck" "Elephant" "Lion")
                 :action '(("Say hello!" . (lambda (req)
                                             (message (concat "Hello" req))))
                           ("Say bye!" . (lambda (req)
                                           (message (concat "Bye " req))))
                           ("Eat" . (lambda (req)
                                      (message (concat "No, we don't eat " req "!")))))
                 :fuzzy-match t)
      :buffer "*helm test*")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested both when I wrote my own code

You can assign any key you want, though the UI (the modeline and the action menu)  assumes F1 to F12.

> change them globally.

As usual, use `C-h k` to learn the key binding: 1) which command it runs 2) which keymap it's attached to. Then use `define-key` to change it.

For example, run your code snippet to enter a helm session, `C-h k <f1>`

> (translated from ) runs the command (lambda nil (interactive)
>   (helm-select-nth-action 0)) (found in helm-map), which is an interactive Lisp
>   function.
>
> It is bound to .
>
> (anonymous)
>
> Not documented.

Let's make `C-c C-c` to do the same as `<f1>`

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (helm-select-nth-action 0))

(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'foo)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And is it possible to also modify the UI to display the new key instead of F1? And for a local change only for my specific code, I can just define the map only locally I guess?

Comment: @tobiasBora No, it's hard-coded https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/d978f20f4c4dae37108a6b50daf320986aeb7dc3/helm.el#L5110

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!